# npm babel ES2015: Getting command lines in the converted/output JS file

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've installed npm (v4.4.4) and babel (v6.24.0) and babel preset 2015.
All running OK when converting ES6 JS to ES5...except a couple of oddities. Maybe someone can see what this newbie is doing wrong.

1) I run babel from npm (see below) which runs OK. I added some script entries into package.JSON to make it work. 
But, UNWANTED oddity...npm inserts the commands into the output JS file. (See below) Is there an npm option to say, don't put the command in the output file.

Yet....if I copy input.JS to the folder with babel.cmd and run it there, I get a clean output.JS. So it looks like npm is inserting the command lines into the output.js file. 
How do I prevent the npm commands being written to output.js. (Obviously I don't want to have my JS files having to share a folder with the .bin files)

2) When I type > babel on the command line in my project folder, I get:
babel: not a command.

I EXPECT THIS. After all, I have not added node_modules/.bin to my PATH env var. Yet every YouTube video I watch about npm and babel, it works. How? No one seems to edit the PATH env var. Am I missing something?

Thanks
Milton.

INPUT JS FILE (input.js)

```
class House {
constructor(v) {
        this.name = v;
}
}
```

OUTPUT JS (TRANSPILED) FILE (output.js) Note 1st 2 lines below...

```
> milton@1.0.0 babel C:\Projects1\01InstallReact4Dev
> babel.cmd "--presets" "es2015" "input.js"

"use strict";

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) 
{ if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }
var House = function House(v) {
  _classCallCheck(this, House);
  this.name = v;
};
```

PACKAGE.JSON

```
"scripts": {
"babel": "babel.cmd",
"babelv": "babel.cmd -V",
"babelh": "babel.cmd -help"
}
```

COMMAND

```
> npm run babel -- --presets es2015 input.js > output.js
```

Thanks Again.
Milton.

Comment: Why not include the input and output fulenames in the `npm` script itself? If you've got lots of files, usually you'd tell Babel to compile one full directory or something.

Comment: npm silent option cures problem 1.  


npm run babel -silent  -- --presets es2015 *.js --out-dir build

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting the output of stdout to the file `output.js`, this includes everything that is displayed. Instead of using the stdout output of babel you can use the `--out-file` or `-o` option. This will write the output to the specified file instead of printing it to stdout (see [Compile Files](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-compile-files)).

Your command would be:

```
npm run babel -- --presets es2015 input.js --out-file output.js
```

> When I type > babel on the command line in my project folder, I get: babel: not a command.

You don't have `node_modules/.bin/` in your shells PATH. You could add it or run it directly with `./node_modules/.bin/babel`. But this is not necessary if you do it in an npm script, because npm will automatically look into `node_modules/.bin/` without it being in your PATH. In this case you could define the following script:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "babel --presets es2015 input.js --out-file output.js"
}
```

And then you can simply run:

```
npm run build
```

If you'd like to transpile more than one file you should use `--out-dir` instead of `--out-file` otherwise they will be concatenated into one file. See also [Compile Directories](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-compile-directories)

Comment: Thank U. Will work on this over weekend..with Final 4 on TV.